# How to find support vectors in a weka model

Tags: java, svm, weka, libsvm

I'm new to weka and I want to write some code in java for classify a data-set using SVM. I want to retrieve the support vector from the weka model.

I previously wrote a python script using LibSVM and it was quite simple. I want to use the SMO classifier to have a 100% weka application, but maybe is an impossible task.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully managed to get support vectors from Weka's model in JAVA with the approach described by David Boho [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_get_support_vector_in_LibSVM_and_Weka).

For people less familiar with JAVA, in addition to [the class](https://gist.github.com/DavidWiesner/2de8a6b2b89ffeaa6d0f) provided by David, I just suggest importing `svm_model` "directly" from LibSVM. See an example with imports [here](https://gist.github.com/mikbuch/c1de199aa70006ff9da15cb0f900fe1c#file-svlibsvm-java-L6).